# From JSON to Typescript interface

Tags: json, dictionary, typescript, interface

I'm going crazy.

I have this JSON:

```
{
    'name': 'Help Me',
    'filters': {
        'filter1': {
            'filter_id': 'wow',
            'filter_query': 'maw',
        },
        'filter2': {
            'filter_id': 'wow',
            'filter_query': 'maw',
        }
    }
}
```

And i'm trying to get this in this way:

```
export interface MyObject {
    name: string;
    filters: Filters;
}

export interface Filters {
    [key: string]: QueryFilter;
}

export interface QueryFilter {
    filter_id: string;
    filter_query: string;
    friendly_filter_query: string;
}
```

Or in this way:

```
export interface MyObject {
name: string;
filters: Map<string, QueryFilter[]>;}
```

But in first case i got this error message:

```
Property 'filters' is missing in type '{ 'name': string; ...'.
```

And in the second case i got this:

```
Property 'clear' is missing in type '{ 'filter1': { 'filter_id': string; 'filter_query': string; }...'.
```

I really can't figure out.

Comment: Can you add to your question the way you use this? The actual code that produces these errors

Comment: I'm simply triying to convert that JSON to Typescript interface, in order to test JSON mock response.
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but your interfaces look alright. So it might have to do with how you're using them. If you'll add that part to your question, or even better link to a playground with your code that has errors, then it will be much easier to help you find the problem.